# Efficient multiplying matrices with different shapes in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I have two matrices A and B:

```
>>>A
[[1,1,1]
[1,1,1]]
>>>B
[2, 3]
```

I want to multiply them efficiently to get such result:

```
>>> A*B
[[2,2,2]
[3,3,3]]
```

I am looking for a more efficient solution than iterate in a loop. Can anyone help?

Comment: What if `B` was `[2, 3]`?

Comment: So then output is: `[[2,2,2] [3,3,3]]`

Comment: So how about `B = [2, 3, 4]` or `B = [2, 3, 4, 5]`?

Comment: Number of row must be equal in both matrices. All values in each column of matrix A are multiplied by value in the same row of matrix B.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`np.multiply`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.multiply.html) to multiply element-wise with broadcasting:

```
A = np.array([[1,1,1],
              [1,1,1]])

B = np.array([2, 3])

res = np.multiply(A, B[:, None])

print(res)

array([[2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3]])
```

Comment: That excacly I am looking for! Element-wise multiplication :) Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Simplest way is just `(A*B.T).T`  But it's probably better to get used to broadcasting:

```
A * B[:, None]
```

This is functionally identical to @jpp's answer with `np.multiply`, but a little shorter to write

Answer (score 2):

Let :

```
>>> A = np.array([[1,1,1], #Shape = (2,3)
          [1,1,1]])
>>> A
Out[3]: 
    array([[1, 1, 1],
          [1, 1, 1]])
>>>B = np.array([2, 3])  # shape = (2,)
```

Both have different shapes so we can't do matrix multiplication(element-wise)
So we can do `A.T` which will convert the shape of the `A` to `(3,2)`

```
>>> (A.T * B).T
Out[7]: 
       array([[2, 2, 2],
              [3, 3, 3]])
```

Answer (score 0):

your question is defying the rules of mathematics.
Matrix A and B cannot be multiplied together because the number of columns in A does not equal the number of rows in B. In this case, the multiplication of these two matrices is not defined

Comment: I think that by 'multiplication' he actually meant `doing something to the matrices`, but he didn't formulate it right so it's unknown what happens in certain situations.

Comment: well yes, I guess

Answer (score -1):

Multiply a 5x3 matrix by a 3x2 matrix (real matrix product)

```
import numpy as np


np_1= np.arange(15).reshape(5,3)


np_2=np.arange(6).reshape(3,2)

np.matmul(np_1,np_2)
```